# PyInstaller can't change the shortcut icon

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, ico

My problem is the following, while i can set any icon i like on the executable itself, i cannot change this one

[image]

I have tried everything but when i select the exe file or when i create a shortcut this PyInstaller icon will come up!

Here is how the exe looks itself

[image]

Here is the tricky part, this DOES NOT happen if i set the option --onefile.
If i generate the stand-alone exe, this "additional" unwanted icon goes away!

and here is the spec file in case you need it:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['Backpack.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Angelo\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-2.1\\Backpack'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)

a.datas += [('back_ico_3.ico', 'C:\\Users\\Angelo\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-2.1\\back_ico_3.ico', 'DATA')]

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Backpack.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='back_ico_3.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='Backpack')
```

Answer (score 13):

I had this same problem, even when using `--onefile`. Cutting and pasting the .exe into a fresh directory worked.

Try deleting `IconCache.db` and rebooting if it still doesn't display your custom icon. It's in `%localappdata%`.

Comment: Cutting and pasting the .exe into a fresh directory worked for me too!

Answer (score 5):

Enable Hidden Items

Go to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`. Select all files that begin with *iconcache* and *thumbcache* and delete all these files

Go to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local` and delete `IconCache.db`

Comment: Need to restart Explorer in task manager before the icons change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='Backpack.exe',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=False , icon='C:\\Users\\Angelo\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-2.1\\back_ico_3.ico')
```